# bind error when doing traceroute

Tags: sockets, bind

I'm not very knowledgeable in named and bind, but after setting up my domain and playing with named (trying to set up my private email server) I ended up probably messing up something. Taceroute does not work anymore, I get a bind error (ping works). Relevant part of "strare traceroute xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is below. Can anybody please guide me to a solution -  thx jankom

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 10
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 11
getuid32()                              = 0
setuid32(0)                             = 0
getpid()                                = 3212
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 12
bind(12, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
dup(2)                                  = 13
fcntl64(13, F_GETFL)                    = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat64(13, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77c3000
_llseek(13, 0, 0xbfc4ebc0, SEEK_CUR)    = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(13, "bind: Invalid argument\n", 23bind: Invalid argument) = 23
) 23
close(13)                               = 0
munmap(0xb77c3000, 4096)                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: Add'l info: (a) correction: "bind" is not as in named or domain but as method bind()

Comment: Add info: (b) traceroute is v: 1.2 from fedora, and it works if I boot to 2.6.20 kernel, but gives "bind error: invalid argument" if I boot to 2.6.32. Configuration of both kernels is the same (aside from some structural differences)

Comment: Add info (c) strace traceroute shown above is meaningless. I get the same output if I do it from 2.6.20 yet the simple tracerout command works there

Comment: Add info last (d): traceroute -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx DOES work from 2.6.32, and only with this -I parameter works from there. Otherwise I get the bind error. So just for curiosity and for the challenge of this problem: why is that? - Thanks, jankom